# I can't access data in a website with xpath and IMPORTXML because pieces of codes is outside of source data

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to get data from the following site: https://www.portaldefinancas.com/framecdi.htm

I'm using google sheets with IMPORTXML function. I learn a little bit about xpath and I believe that my problem isn't syntax.

The problem is that it seems this website do not want that people get data from it.

The piece of code I need from the source code is following:

```html
... </fieldset><div class="column50"><script src="js-gen-ctb/tb-tb.js"></script>
Taxas CDI - Mensal - Anual - Acumulada - 2021
<script src="js-tx-ctb/th-cdib.js"></script>
<script src="js-tx/cdib-2021.js"></script> ...
```

As you can see, at the exact point the data should appear there is a lot of scripts. When I access these scripts the only thing that is inside of them is a document.write piece of code, like this:

```html
document.write(""),document.write('<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" id="tb"><caption><p class="cp">');
```

The only function of these scripts is to group the source code in many parts in different files.

In this way, I can't access data because the function IMPORTXML return #NA error since the data is outside of source code.

Is there any way to I get data using the function IMPORTXML in this case? how can I access the data inside a .js file with this formula?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data can be retrieved by parsing the contents of html table in js files as follows

```
function getTaxas(url) {
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  source = source.split('document')[2]
  var table = '<table><tr><td' + source.match(/(?<=td).*(?=td)/g) + 'td></tr></table>'
  var doc = XmlService.parse(table);
  var rows = doc.getDescendants().filter(function(c) {
    var element = c.asElement();
    return element && element.getName() == "tr";
  });
  var data = rows.slice(0).map(function(row) {
    return row.getChildren("td").map(function(cell) {
      return cell.getValue();
    });
  });
  return data; 
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18yhDYr91ORrofV20FMWYmYnwwnGK0QaQguG9uLdP5co/copy